# With Using UnityContainer and Web Api, An error say Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have an api mvc project which for some of method when i call the action. it gives me an error like this:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error
>   occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'ReserveController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public
>   constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Type
>   'Jabama.Web.API.Controllers.ReserveController' does not have a default
>   constructor","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)"}}

Here is my api config class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {


            var container = new UnityContainer();

            Jabama.Core.Services.Config.UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(container);

            container.RegisterType<Core.Services.Search.IAutoCompoleteSearchService, Core.Services.Search.AutoCompoleteSearchService>();
            container.RegisterType<Core.Services.Common.IImageService, Core.Services.Common.ImageService>();
            container.RegisterType<Core.Services.Search.ICitySearchService, Core.Services.Search.CitySearchService>();
            container.RegisterType<Core.Services.ContentPanel.ICityService, Core.Services.ContentPanel.CityService>();

            container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => new FakeOWINAuth()));
            container.RegisterType<IDataProtectionProvider>(new InjectionFactory(o => Startup.DataProtectionProvider));
            container.RegisterType<Core.Services.Common.IUserManagerService, Core.Services.Common.UserManagerService>();

            container.RegisterType<Core.Services.FrontEnd.IOrderService, Core.Services.FrontEnd.OrderService>();

            container.RegisterType<Core.Services.FrontEnd.IPlaceService, Core.Services.FrontEnd.PlaceService>();

             CurrentUnityContainer.Container = container;

            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);



            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  }
    }
```

This is my CurrentUnityContainer

```
 internal static class CurrentUnityContainer
    {
        internal static IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
    }
```

My UnityResolver

```
  public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        protected IUnityContainer container;

        public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
            return new UnityResolver(child);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

and this is my ReserveContoller which has been caused error in it

```
[RoutePrefix("v1/Reserve")]
    public ReserveController(IOrderService orderService, IPaymentService paymentService, ISMSService smsService, IUserManagerService userService, IEventService eventService, ITourService tourService)
    {
        _orderService = orderService;
        _paymentService = paymentService;
        _smsService = smsService;
        _userService = userService;
        _eventService = eventService;
        _tourService = tourService;

    }

    [Route("guests")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<UpdateResult<long>> SaveGuestInfo(long? orderId, long roomId, List<GuestInformationViewModel> guestList, string catKey, string placeKey, string checkIn, string checkOut ,Dictionary<string, string> rooms, string copoun , string guestRequirements)
    {
        //rooms  : roomId-roomServiceId

        Jabama.Core.Services.FrontEndViewModel.OrderViewModel order = 
            new Jabama.Core.Services.FrontEndViewModel.OrderViewModel();
        order.OrderId = orderId ?? 0;

        order.orderDetails =
            new List<Jabama.Core.Services.FrontEndViewModel.OrderDetailsViewModel>();




        VerifyOrderViewModel verifyOrder =_orderService.getVerifyOrder("fa", catKey,
                               placeKey, checkIn, checkOut, rooms, null, null, guestList);

        bool isNewOrder = false;
        if (order.OrderId == 0)
            isNewOrder = true;
        order.languageKey = verifyOrder.languageKey;
        order.placeKey = verifyOrder.placeKey;
        order.catKey = verifyOrder.catKey;
        order.CheckIn = verifyOrder.CheckIn;
        order.CheckOut = verifyOrder.CheckOut;


        order.Copoun = copoun;
        order.GuestRequirements = guestRequirements;
        order.UserName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity?.Name;//verifyOrder.UserName;

        string roomsName = "";
        int j = 0;
        int w = 0;
        foreach (var od in verifyOrder.orderDetails)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < od.RoomCount; i++)
            {
                var detail = new Jabama.Core.Services.FrontEndViewModel.OrderDetailsViewModel();
                if (catKey == "tour")
                {
                    detail.GuestInformation = guestList.Where(d => d.IsHeadMan == true).ToList()[w];
                    detail.GuestInformationId = guestList.Where(d => d.IsHeadMan == true).ToList()[w].Id;
                }
                else//hotel
                {
                    detail.GuestInformation = guestList[j];
                    j++;
                }
                try
                {
                    detail.AdultCount = (short)od.AdultCount;
                    detail.InfantCount = (short)od.InfantCount;
                    detail.ChildCount = (short)od.ChildCount;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }

                detail.RoomId = od.RoomId;
                detail.Capacity = od.Capacity;
                detail.ExtraCapacity = od.ExtraCapacity;
                detail.Breakfast = od.Breakfast;
                detail.Dinner = od.Dinner;
                detail.Lunch = od.Lunch;
                detail.MenuType = od.MenuType;

                order.orderDetails.Add(detail);

                roomsName += od.RoomName.Replace("اتاق", "");
                if (verifyOrder.orderDetails.Last() != od)
                    roomsName += ",";
            }
            w++;
        }

        var orderResult = await _orderService.GenerateOrder(order);
        if (orderResult.IsSuccess)
        {

            if (isNewOrder)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string userPhone = _userService.GetUserBy(order.UserName).PhoneNumber;
                        var notification = _eventService.GetEmailUsersForEvent("NewOrder");
                        double nights = 0;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(verifyOrder.CheckIn) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(verifyOrder.CheckOut))
                            nights = (verifyOrder.CheckOut.ToMiladiDateTime() - verifyOrder.CheckIn.ToMiladiDateTime()).TotalDays;

                        if (notification.RecevierNumber.Count() != 0)
                        {
                            _smsService.SendSMS(notification.RecevierNumber, string.Format(notification.SendedMessage, orderResult.ViewModel,
                                                                                                                         verifyOrder.PlaceName.Trim(),
                                                                                                                         verifyOrder.CheckIn,
                                                                                                                         nights,
                                                                                                                         verifyOrder.Phone1,
                                                                                                                         userPhone, roomsName, verifyOrder.CityName.Trim()), "NewOrder");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }).Start();
            }
            return orderResult;

        }
        else
        {
            if (orderResult.StatusCode == 2)
            {
                return orderResult; 
            }
            else if (orderResult.StatusCode == 3)
            {                   
                return orderResult;
            }
            else
            {
                return orderResult;
            }
        }
    }




}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what's my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you resolve the dependencies for all the interfaces that referred in ReserveController constructor to resolve this issue. Based on your code it seems unity has not resolved dependencies for below interaces.
ISMSService 
IPaymentService 
ITourService 
IEventService

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parameterless constructor to your `ReserveController` class...

Something like this:

```
public ReserveController() {}  //parameterless constructor for Unity

[RoutePrefix("v1/Reserve")]
public ReserveController(IOrderService orderService, IPaymentService paymentService, ISMSService smsService, IUserManagerService userService, IEventService eventService, ITourService tourService)
{

...
```